# Sorting with mongodb problem for next and prev document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

[see files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1TEi.png)

My issues: I have some file lists which are shown in desc order. And I have a show the next and prev item of files for individual users depending on file id.

So the problem is: if the timestamp / createdAt time is the same then the next and prev id not properly shown. If I use `id $gt` and `$lt` there is also issues to get next and prev id.

File model:

1. _id,
2. uploaded by(user model _id),
3. status(Not Started, Complete)
4. fileName.

I used these queries to show the table which is in the images.

```
db.files.find({status: "Not Started"}).sort(
  {createdAt: -1, fileName: -1}).limit(10).skip(limit * (pageNo -1))
```

which show as compass in desc order. In this query files are showing as expected in compass where I sort this same queries.

When I go through each file, for file no 6 or 7, because these file timestamps are same, I used these queries for the next and prev.

Because if I go by next prev file, then I have to show exactly db are showing file one after another.

NEXT id:->

```
db.files.find({
    createdAt: {$gte: "2022-12-08T18.00.00.000", $lte: "2022-12-08T17.59.59.999"},
    uploadedBy: {$in:["35495", "545454"]},
    status: "Not Started"},
    createdeAt:{$lte: "2022-12-08T19:07:985"}, 
    _id: {$lt: 63254444444105
}).sort({
    createdAt: -1, fileName:-1
}).limit(1)
```

prev id: ->

```
db.files.find({
    createdAt: {$gte: "2022-12-08T18.00.00.000", $lte: "2022-12-08T17.59.59.999"}, 
    uploadedBy: {$in:["35495", "545454"]}, 
    status: "Not Started"}, 
    createdeAt:{$gte: "2022-12-08T19:07:985"}, 
    _id: {$gt: 63254444444105
}).sort({
    createdAt: 1, fileName:1
}).limit(1)
```

The next and prev not same as table in picture if I used these queries.

If anything needed to understand more, please reply.

Comment: Please provide few sample documents

Answer (score 0):

If the `createdAt` value is not unique then you will not be able to uniquely identify a document using only `createdAt`.

The selected sort key is `{createdAt:- 1, fileName: -1}`, so if the `fileName` is unique, you could find next next item in the order by searching for the first document that both has a `createdAt` and a `fileName` that are less than the current document.